# Oracle PL/SQL seems to ignore WHERE clause of my Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

I have a table of club´s members with a column of status that a want to use as a filter in my function below. But the result is always the same no matter what number I pass as a function parameter. The count always comes with the total registers of the entire table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_count_members
(id_status in club.members.id_status%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
total club.members.id%TYPE:=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO total 
    FROM club.members m
    WHERE m.id_status = id_status; 
    RETURN total; 
END;
```

And the query:

```
select id_status, fn_count_members(1) as total from club.members;
```

[image]

What am I missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: `fn_count_members(1)` != `fn_count_members(id_status)` . Eg just convert the fixed value `1` to `id_status`

Comment: Littlefoot gave you the answer, and a way to fix it. To understand the problem, you need to familiarize yourself with "name resolution" - what happens if the same name is used for more than one "thing". In your `where` clause, one `id_status` is qualified (by `m`) so there is no confusion. The other one is not qualified. In the query, the first choice is "a column from the table". There is such a column, so **that** is what will be used. It won't be the argument passed to the function. Then - there are other fixes (besides what Littlefoot showed), but that is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_count_members(
  p_id_status in club.members.id_status%TYPE  -- change the parameter name to
                                              -- something different from the
                                              -- column name.
)
RETURN NUMBER IS
total club.members.id%TYPE:=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO total 
    FROM club.members m
    WHERE m.id_status = p_id_status;          -- and here
    RETURN total; 
END;
/
```

Then you need to pass the parameter in rather than using `1`:

```sql
select id_status,
       fn_count_members(id_status) as total
from   club.members;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=917875b9681ce3ef0365b5559a335124)*

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
(id_status in club.members.id_status%TYPE)
 ---------
 this
```

Because, when used in `where` clause

```
WHERE m.id_status = id_status
```

it turns out to be something like `where 1 = 1` and returns *everything*, no filtering at all.

**Rename** parameter to e.g.

```
(par_id_status in club.members.id_status%TYPE)
```

and use it as

```
WHERE m.id_status = par_id_status
```

Comment: Thank you very much!